# How can I use SQL to find results with a dynamic integer field?

Tags: type-conversion, integer, where-clause, nvarchar

| ID | Status |

I am searching a table with a status field that is an integer. I need to find certain values with the dynamic status. The status can be 0 or 0,1 or 1,3 or 0,1,3 etc.
I get an error message when trying to use IN.

The status value is an integer type value.

```
Select *
From FinancialScheduledTransaction
Where Status IN (@Status)
```

`Error Message: Query Error! Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0,1' to data type int.`

Comment: @Status should be a table valued parameter (a little table of numbers), not a string. Or, otherwise, you will have to transform that string into a set of numbers so that `'0,1'` becomes the number `0` and `1` - you will see various forms of "string_split" functions that do this (depending on what database you are using).